# How would you group up articles by context? - Natural Language

Tags: python, data-mining, nlp

**I have lists of articles made of:
title, subtitle and body.**

Now I need to parse all these articles and **group them up under different context categories** or sub categories based on their possible **keywords**.

> **e.g.** if the article is likely to be related to sports cars then the article would be associated with the car or/and vehicle context

---

Now I understand that this is a vast ocean, but this is also why I have put up this question. Because the ocean of solutions might be too big for me, and I would most likely get lost and adopt some bad thought solution.

There are probably some popular and standardized ways of doing this that I do not know, and it would be very useful if someone pointed me in the right direction.

Help would be great. =)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Library_of_Congress_Classification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Natural Lanugage Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/) but don't expect that there is a magic bullet in there which will keep you having to learn a fair bit about linguistics, as the problem you describe cannot be solved wholly mechanically.